# Javascript checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I want to know the number of checboxes checked in javascript. If only one checkbox is checked then it should show an alert message, otherwise it should do the processing. I tried `if(names[i].checked>2)` but it is not working.. Please help.

```
function insert_slide(ed, height, width)

{ var img=new Array();

var names=document.getElementsByName('image_id');


for(i=0;i<names.length;i++)
{
if(names[i].checked)
{
    img[i] = "<IMG SRC='" + names[i].value + "'";






    if(height != '') {
        img[i] += " height='" + height + "'";
    }
    if(width != '') {
        img[i] += " width='" + width + "'"; 
    }
    img[i] += " style='margin: 5px;' >";

    editor.nicCommand("insertHTML", img[i]);
}}
    hide_lightwindow();
}
```

Comment: `names[i].checked>2` will just compare a boolean value against `2` and this will always be false. You want to count the element in `names` for whitch `names[i].checked` is true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be the following:

```
function check(form) {
var sum = 0;
max = form.box.length;
  for(i=0; i<max; i++) {
    if(form.box[i].checked) {
      sum+=1;
    }
  }
  if (sum==1) {alert("one is checked")}
  else {alert("more than one are checked") }
}
```

Get the `lenght` of  all chechboxes in a `form`. Then check with a `for` loop, if there are `checked` chechboxes, for each one it finds adds `1` in the variable `sum`

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/ezafal/2

Answer (score 0):

So easy with [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com). You should check into it as your primary JS framework:

```
if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 1)
{
    alert('Only one checked');
}
else
{
    // Do code
}
```

Comment: *"Use jQuery"* is not an answer to this question. It is not really difficult with plain JS either...

Comment: fix your spelling, the selector is `:checked`, not `:cheked` :)

Comment: That's how programming works, Matt :) If we all wanted blazing fast websites we'd be coding in C and COBOL. Anytime we reduce syntax verbosity for ease of use and cross-platform compatibility, the trade-off is generally performance. The good news is that my phone's CPU today is faster than my server's CPU 10 years ago when I coded native JS, so I think it's a perfectly acceptable trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

If names contains the checkboxes, this could be a counter:

```
var countChecked = 0;
for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
  countChecked += /checkbox/i.test(names[i].type) && names[i].checked ? 1 : 0;
}
if (countChecked === 1) {
 // alert something
} else {
 // proces
}
```